# RGB values not changing until first input has been altered

Tags: javascript, html

I have an extremely simple script on my webpage which allows users to change the `background` color of an element; based on the *rgb slider values*.

It works, however, in order for it to update the elements `background` `rgb()`, the uppermost `input` slider value has to have been changed.

The way the script is **supposed** to work, is when any of the slider values are changed, the `background` `rgb()` value is changed along with it.

This is my **JavaScript**:

```
var input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("input", function(){

    var red = document.getElementById("red").value,
        green = document.getElementById("green").value,
        blue = document.getElementById("blue").value;

    var display = document.getElementById("display");

    display.style.background = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";

});
```

And my **HTML**:

```
<div class="picker">
    Red <input type="range" min="0" max="255", step="1" id="red">
    Green <input type="range" min="0" max="255", step="1" id="green">
    Blue <input type="range" min="0" max="255", step="1" id="blue">

    <div id="display"></div>
</div>
```

I feel like it may have something to do with `document.querySelector("input")`, however, I am unsure as I am pretty new to **pure JavaScript**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns single element thus it works for first input.

You need to use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a list of the elements. You need to iterate it to bind event handler with individual element.

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].addEventListener("input", function() {
        var red = document.getElementById("red").value,
            green = document.getElementById("green").value,
            blue = document.getElementById("blue").value;

        var display = document.getElementById("display");
        display.style.background = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="picker">
    Red
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" , step="1" id="red">
    Green
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" , step="1" id="green">
    Blue
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" , step="1" id="blue">
    <div id="display">Yahooooooooooooo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But what is the reason for the `for` loop? what does it do

Comment: @Caelan., `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a list of the elements. You need to iterate it to bind event handler.

Comment: Ohhh, I did not know that! Thankyou :-)